# alternative for document.Write()

Tags: javascript, kajabi

hi iam trying to append a form in my website but it's not working it keeps telling me
`Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.`

the embed code was `<script src=https://courses.nooor.me/forms/2148061262/embed.js></script>`
and when i printed the src into the url it was like that

```
(function() {
  // write the form
  document.write("<link href=\'//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700\' rel=\'stylesheet\' type=\'text/css\'>\n<link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"all\" href=\"https://kajabi-app-assets.kajabi-cdn.com/assets/form_embed-70ab594381937fc46cadbbaab29c12b724dc077086662f2bbd495c08e46bb08d.css\" />\n<script src=\"https://kajabi-app-assets.kajabi-cdn.com/assets/form_embed-fd7a5360fe56f0a332f934492d89f18c2202d65871804504adca6fd4b6e78ceb.js\"><\/script>\n\n<div id=\"kajabi-form\" class=\"kajabi-form--inline\">\n  <form data-parsley-validate=\"true\" data-kjb-disable-on-submit=\"true\" action=\"https://courses.nooor.me/forms/2148061262/form_submissions\" accept-charset=\"UTF-8\" method=\"post\"><input name=\"utf8\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"&#x2713;\" /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"authenticity_token\" value=\"jCZsvmdl6JVqAAh+p7QdKNDiBgrYxMUJIjX/El9vUKHhUVU+BeaAYYhRCHp5rLDDGS1//6FYFmbbbbQSfeQ+9g==\" />\n      <style id=\"form-embed-style\" type=\"text/css\">\n\n  <\/style>\n\n\n<div class=\"kajabi-form__content\">\n  <div class=\"kajabi-form__title\">JOIN THE NEWSLETTER<\/div>\n  <div class=\"kajabi-form__subtitle\">\n    <p style=\"text-align: center;\">Subscribe to get our latest content by email.<\/p>\n  <\/div>\n  <fieldset>\n      <div class=\"text-field kajabi-form__form-item\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"form_submission[name]\" id=\"form_submission_name\" value=\"\" required=\"required\" placeholder=\"Name\" /><\/div>\n      <div class=\"email-field kajabi-form__form-item\"><input required=\"required\" placeholder=\"Email\" data-parsley-remote=\"true\" data-parsley-remote-validator=\"kjb_email_validator\" type=\"email\" name=\"form_submission[email]\" id=\"form_submission_email\" /><\/div>\n      <div class=\"phone-field kajabi-form__form-item\"><input placeholder=\"WhatsApp Number\" type=\"tel\" name=\"form_submission[phone_number]\" id=\"form_submission_phone_number\" /><\/div>\n      <button class=\"kajabi-form__btn kajabi-form__btn--block-mobile\" type=\"submit\">Subscribe<\/button>\n  <\/fieldset>\n<\/div>\n\n<\/form><\/div>\n");
})();
```

`so is there is anyway to alter it to make it work without document.write

Comment: The error tells you that you can't do this. You can add a `<Link>` tag to the HEAD using the DOM though.

Comment: Where are you trying to do this?  If it's static, why not just put the code directly into the page?

Comment: i did put the code in the page but it didn't work

Comment: i did also tried the <link> but it didn't work